# Login com CQRS fica no Command ou Query?

Tags: java, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net-core, cqrs

Olá, vou fazer Login na mão (não usaria Identity ou qualquer outra lib ou serviço) estou usando CQRS, gostaria de saber se devo colocar o Login como Command ou como Query, tendo em vista que só vai existir uma lógica que verifica se o usuário e senha existem e depois retorna o Token.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, na minha visão CQRS é relevante quando você, dentro de um mesmo contexto delimitado, possui fluxos de inserção ou obtenção de dados, sendo interessante utilizar-se de um handler para cada caso de uso de seu negócio (business). Como o seu serviço de login terá apenas a responsabilidade de responder se o usuário está no banco e retornar o token, imagino que seja JWT, não vejo o real ganho nesse cenário para o uso de CQRS. Uma API acessando um classe de Serviço possivelmente já atenderia.